# google analytics duplicate url with unicode character

Tags: google-analytics, internal-link

when I checked my google *analytics > acquisition > search console > landing* page
understand that I have 2 URLs for each blog post.
for example:

> blog/429/legal/اسقاط-کافه-خیارات-به-چه-معناست/

and

> /blog/429/legal/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B7-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%81%D9%87-%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D9%87-%DA%86%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA/

Both refer to one blog post.

But the main problem is statistics:

[image: my google analytics screen shot]

URL #2 have 0 Impressions, clicks and CTR but correct position. Also URL #1 have correct Impressions, clicks and ctr, but incorrect position.

My blog posts have canonical tag and I check all internal link building. I used all linked with same form (for example: `example.com/blog/429/legal/اسقاط-کافه-خیارات-به-چه-معناست/`)

now

1- what is the source of problem and

2- how to fix it?

Comment: You should only use the Latin alphabet for URLs.

Comment: Try to use Final URL of Google Ads report in Google Analytics to understand if that url depend on Google Ads link

Comment: this post should probably move to superuser, not sure there is a coding problem space here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of Google Search Console. The url is sent to Google Analytics in encoded form and the tool manages to convert it to show ad decoded. When it retrieves it from the search console it shows it as it receives it. I don't think there is an effective solution with the two tools, however you can export data and manage them in another tool, for example with Javascript (i.e. in Spreadsheet and Google Apps Script) you can de decode a URI with only one operation so after that you can build a table (in Spreadsheet) that finds the matches and compare the metrics.

```
<div id="get_url_encoded">/blog/429/legal/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B7-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%81%D9%87-%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D9%87-%DA%86%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA/</div>
<br /><br />
<div id="set_url_decoded"></div>

<script>
var uri = document.getElementById("get_url_encoded").innerHTML;
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri);
document.getElementById("set_url_decoded").innerHTML = uri_dec;
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/michelepisani/de058c4o/5/